# How to reduce impact of false positive images in Tensorflow Object Detection Framework?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, object-detection

I am training a single object detector(for car) with Faster R-CNN with Inception v2 config file. I started with around 300 examples of images of the object with bounding boxes and trained that, got decent results, but when running on images that don't contain that object, would often get false matches with high confidence (sometimes .99).

When I am testing with an image of ball, it shows this ball as car with bounding box and prediction score 90%.

So, is there any way how to reduce this impact of negative images.
Or is there any way to train the model with negative images in Tensorflow Object Detection Framework.

Any working suggestion is highly appreciated.